# Android: Cant get data to display in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I cant get my data to display in ListView. I have removed all unnecessary code to keep this simple. The program works fine, but the only data that is displayed is "Model.Locations @ 421ec04eo" Why is this happening?

PinPoint Class

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.locations);

        ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        ArrayList<Locations> items = new ArrayList<Locations>();
        Locations sr1 = new Locations();
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) 
        {
            sr1.setAdress("Blablabla");
            sr1.setTitle("Home");
            sr1.setDistance("200m");
            items.add(sr1);
        }

        ArrayAdapter<Locations> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Locations>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, items);

        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

Location class

    package Model;


    public class Locations 
    {
    int midlat;
    int midlong;
    String title;
    String adress;
    String distance;

    public int getMidlat() {
        return midlat;
    }


    public String getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }


    public void setDistance(String distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }


    public void setMidlat(int i) {
        this.midlat = i;
    }


    public int getMidlong() {
        return midlong;
    }


    public void setMidlong(int midlong) {
        this.midlong = midlong;
    }


    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }


    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }


    public String getAdress() {
        return adress;
    }


    public void setAdress(String adress) {
        this.adress = adress;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.toString();
    }
}

locations XML.FILE

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toptext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override the `toString()` method of your custom type, which you started to do, but then just called the super which negates the purpose of overriding it in the first place.

Make the `toString()` return what you want the arrayadapter to display in the `ListView` i.e.

```
@Override
public String toString(){
  return title + address + distance;
}
```

Of course, this is just an example, you can implement it to fit your needs.

Also, the reason is because `ArrayAdapter<T>` by default calls the `toString()` method of the custom type to populate the `TextView` in the current row of the `ListView`. If you need the list to show something special above what you can put together in the overrided toString method you will have to create a custom adapter.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an array of memory addresses to the adapter, so it is expected.

```
ArrayAdapter<Locations> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Locations>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, items);
```

If you want to display the address, title and distance in your views, please consider a custom listview.

Answer (score 1):

The basic ArrayAdapter just uses the Map.Location.toString() to populate the ListView's item views. With a basic ArrayAdapter the default item view is a TextView. In order to properly display your location you can override the toString() function to what you want it to show for a Map.Location instance:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
*"String that you want"*
}
```

Or another way would to be create a custom BaseAdapter and override the getView() method of your custom BaseAdapter to show a specialize layout.xml. Look [here](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429) for instructions.

Comment: Sorry in your case the item views would be CheckedTextViews.